# How can I let Arduino GSM shield respond only to authorized numbers?

Tags: arduino, gsm

I am working on a project where I send '1' to my Arduino GSM Shield to switch on the LED connected to pin 13 and I switch it off by sending '0', but I would like to modify the code in order for the GSM Shield to respond only to the number specified. Here is my code, in my case I used an example phone number. Currently when I send a message from adminNumber the LED does not switch on nor off.

```cpp
// include the GSM library
#include <GSM.h>

// PIN Number for the SIM
#define PINNUMBER ""

// initialize the library instances
GSM gsmAccess;
GSM_SMS sms;

// Array to hold the number a SMS is retreived from

char senderNumber[20];
char adminNumber[20]="+123456789234";


void setup()
{

  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  // initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  Serial.println("SMS Messages Receiver");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM connection
  while (notConnected)
  {
    if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("GSM initialized");
  Serial.println("Waiting for messages");
}


void loop()
{
  char c;

  sms.remoteNumber(senderNumber, 20);
  sms.remoteNumber(adminNumber, 20);

    // If there are any SMSs available()
  if (sms.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Message received from:");

     // Get remote number
    sms.remoteNumber(senderNumber, 20);
    Serial.println(senderNumber);


       // Any number besides admin number will not change the state of the pin
    while(adminNumber == senderNumber){
        // Any messages starting with 1 will set pin 13 to HIGH
if (sms.peek() == '1'){
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
     sms.flush();
    }
        // Any messages starting with 0 will set pin 13 to LOW
else if(sms.peek() == '0'){
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);

        sms.flush()
}
    }



    // Read message bytes and print them
    while (c = sms.read())
      Serial.print(c);

    Serial.println("\nEND OF MESSAGE");

    // Delete message from modem memory
    sms.flush();
    Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
  }

  delay(1000);


}
```

Comment: Why are you putting the checking for 1 and 0 in a loop? It seems to me that it will never exit that loop.

Comment: You also seem to have too many closing curly braces in the loop()

Comment: I used the while loop so that it will only turn on the LED when the senderNumber is equal to the adminNumber...

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code of what you mean?

Comment: Rather use an IF. The loop() method will loop in anyway. You can maybe change the if (sms.available()) to while (sms.available())

Comment: I tried it but it did't work... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Array comparison can be donne like Kurz7 does https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/41972-how-do-i-compare-two-arrays.html

```cpp
// include the GSM library
#include <GSM.h>
#include <string.h>

// PIN Number for the SIM
#define PINNUMBER "xxxx"

// initialize the library instances
GSM gsmAccess;
GSM_SMS sms;

// Array to hold the number a SMS is retreived from
char senderNumber[20];
char adminNumber[20]="+xxxxxxxxxxx";

void setup()
{

// initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

// initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("SMS Messages Receiver");

// connection state
boolean notConnected = true;

// Start GSM connection
while (notConnected)
{
 if (gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY)
 notConnected = false;
 else
{
 Serial.println("Not connected");
 delay(1000);
 }
 }

Serial.println("GSM initialized");
Serial.println("Waiting for messages");
}

void loop()
{
char c;

// If there are any SMSs available()
if (sms.available())

{
Serial.println("Message received from:");
sms.remoteNumber(senderNumber,20); // Get remote number
Serial.println(senderNumber);

// Any number besides admin number will not change the state of the pin

if (strcmp( adminNumber, senderNumber ) == 0 )
{

// Any messages starting with 1 will set pin 13 to HIGH

if (sms.peek() == '1') {digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

}
// Any messages starting with 0 will set pin 13 to LOW
else if(sms.peek() == '0') {digitalWrite(13, LOW);

}

// Read message bytes and print them
while (c = sms.read())
Serial.print(c);

Serial.println("\nEND OF MESSAGE");

// Delete message from modem memory
sms.flush();
Serial.println("MESSAGE DELETED");
}

delay(1000);

}}
```